# How can I use filter predicates for a geometry column?

Tags: python, geopandas, pyarrow

When reading a DataFrame from a parquet file using `pandas.read_parquet`, I can use the [pyarrow filters](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html) API to read only a subset of rows.  This equally works for geopandas.  For example:

```py
gdf = geopandas.read_parquet(files, filters=[("station", "in", ["sjisjka", "kaitum"]))
```

How can I use this for a geometry column?  I could do it explicitly:

```py
gdf = geopandas.read_parquet(files)
pol = shapely.geometry.Polygon(((65, 15), (65, 25), (70, 25), (70, 15), (65, 15)))
selection = gdf[gdf["location"].within(pol)]
```

but this is relatively slow (even if using dask/dask-geopandas).  Is there a way to apply such a location search directly using an arrow filter?

```py
gdf = dask_geopandas.read_parquet(files, filters=[("location", "within", pol)])
```

doesn't work (unsurprisingly). but fails with

```
ValueError: "('location', 'within', <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7fd5ffa7ce80>)" is not a valid operator in predicates.
```

Comment: You should be able to use a UDF, as described [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/compute.html#user-defined-functions).  As the docs mention, that API is experimental (and there are some proposals to change it) but I would guess most of the changes would be around how you register the UDF.

That will move the compute earlier, inside of pyarrow, though I don't know how significant of savings you will get.  If the goal is to reduce the amount of data read from disk then you would need a pushdown UDF which doesn't exist today (though one could make a PR :))

Comment: A pushdown UDF would be based on statistics though, and I don't know how a polygon is stored in parquet so I don't know whether it would even be possible.  I suspect geo-aware disk indices is a whole topic on its own

Comment: How many rows are in this file? When you use dask, how many partitions are you using and what kind of cluster?

Comment: @PaulH the files have around 250 million rows so far, but I expect that to increase to around 1–2 billion as I increase the time over which I do my processing.  The geographic filter should decrease it by about a factor 3.  I have not yet tried optimising dask partitions or the type of cluster; by default it uses `npartitions=365`. I'm using the default single-machine threaded scheduler, if I'm understanding your question about the cluster correctly.

Comment: OK yeah, if you're still using a single-machine threaded scheduler (no cluster), I won't expect too much performance gains from local dask. For 2 billion rows, I'd start to consider scaling out to proper cluster.